# How to redirect output of a console to the console that launched it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, scripting, command-prompt

I am launching a bat file from a command prompt. How do I log the outputs of this launched console to the console that launched it? Below is what I'm doing in y console.

```
cd develop/scripts
start build.bat
```

I need the output of build.bat to appear in the console which launched it.

Please advice.

Comment: You should edit your question and post your code !

Comment: done. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Try `Cmd /k build.bat`

Comment: Start makes it an Explorer command line. Your command tells it to not put it in the same console. See `start /?`.

Comment: Ditch the START command and run build.bat directly.

Comment: @Hackoo Thanks for the reply. That did the trick :) please post it as an answer

Comment: You probably want `cmd /c` rather than `cmd /k`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks mate! It would terminate the new console :)

Comment: I wanted a way to get the output to the console that launched it and Hackoo's answer does just that. I don't see any issue here

Comment: So you really are saying `cmd /k build.bat` and not `start cmd /k build.bat` ?

Comment: of course! It worked when I tried with cmd /k.

Comment: What happens if you just say `build.bat` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that :

```
cd develop/scripts
Cmd /k build.bat
```

Comment: It should be `cmd /c` not `cmd /k`.  The `/k` means that the child shell remains open until the user explicitly closes it.  If you run these commands repeatedly, you'll wind up with a new instance of `cmd` each time.

Comment: (Also, you *could* just say `build`, unless there's a specific reason to run the batch file in a child shell.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I don't know why you downvote this answer since it is accepted by the OP ?

Comment: If the OP knew what he was doing, he wouldn't have asked the question in the first place. :-)  Using `cmd /k` instead of `start` "works" in the sense that he gets the output in the same console, but each time he runs it he's launching another process.  After a few hours or days he might have hundreds or thousands of redundant processes, and eventually that's going to cause performance problems.

Comment: ... although after his cryptic comment above I've started to wonder whether he's misunderstood you and is using `start cmd /k` :-)

Comment: Hence "misunderstood", although `start cmd /k` would at least be harmless.